# Change image after button click using MahApps Metro

Tags: wpf, button, mahapps.metro

I am using MahApps Metro anf this is my `Button`:

```
<Button
    Name="startBtn"
    Width="55"
    Height="55"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}"
    Click="playBtn_Click">
    <Rectangle
      Width="25"
      Height="25">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <ImageBrush                         
                ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Resources/start.ico" />
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
</Button>
```

So all i want is change the `Button` `image` inside my `Button Click Event`:

```
private void startBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAML:

```
<Button
   Name="startBtn"
   Width="55"
   Height="55"
   VerticalAlignment="Top"
   Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}"
   Click="playBtn_Click">
   <Image Width="25" Height="25" Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/start.ico" />
</Button>
```

Code:

```
private void startBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     ((sender as Button).Content as Image).Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("yourpath.png"));
}
```